# MYSQLI only fetching first row

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code

```
// Connect to server and select database.
$conn =  new mysqli($host, $username, $password, 'gs') ;
if($conn->connect_errno){
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$result = $conn->query("SELECT gs_users.id, gs_user_objects.imei, gs_objects.lat, gs_objects.lng,
gs_objects.dt_server, gs_objects.name, gs_objects.odometer, 
tablet_dispatch.destination, tablet_dispatch.reg, tablet_dispatch.d_name
FROM gs_users 
INNER JOIN gs_user_objects ON gs_users.id = gs_user_objects.user_id
INNER JOIN gs_objects ON gs_user_objects.imei = gs_objects.imei
INNER JOIN tablet_dispatch ON gs_objects.name = tablet_dispatch.reg
WHERE tablet_dispatch.client_id = '299' 
")
        or trigger_error($conn->error);
$rows = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_BOTH);
?>

         <tr>
          <td><a href="#!"><? echo $rows['reg']; ?></a></td>
          <td><? echo $rows['d_name']; ?></td>
          <td><? echo $rows['destination']; ?></td>
          <td><? echo $rows['lat']; ?>, <? echo $rows['lng']; ?></td>
          <td><? echo $rows['dt_server']; ?></td>
         </tr>
```

It is drawing the information from the Database but only displaying the first row. I need to show all the rows as per the query

[image]

Comment: try to use `group by`

Comment: @MoizAhmad doesn't work using groupd by

Comment: what is your expected result? Can you show me database structure please

Comment: @MoizAhmad I have added the query result I want to see with tablet structures

Comment: It is showing the results but only the first line

Comment: Replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`.  also remove `group by`

Comment: Same result just first line

Comment: can you create sqlfiddle of your database...so i can try some quries...